# Open Table in HTML from Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, dialog, modal-dialog

I created a table that I have in my html that I am trying to access from a button (PMSelect) that I also have in my html. The table (script id="utilitySelectorTmpl") and javascript (utilitySelectorModule.js to query the restpage) to populate the table are done. I have not been able to open the table using onclick. This is what I have:

```
var utilitySelectorToolBtn = dom.byId("PMSelect");
    on(utilitySelectorToolBtn, "click", function (event) {
    if (app.isutilitySelectorModuleOpen === true) {
        app.utilitySelectorModule.hide();
        app.isUtilitySelectorOpen = false;
    } else { // not open
      app.utilitySelectorModule.show();
      app.isutilitySelectorModuleOpen = true;
     }
 });
```

I haven't yet specified the location of table when open. Maybe this could be the reason but I am not sure. This is a portion of my script:

```
app.utilitySelectorModule = {
   countyField: 'Cnty',
   routeField: 'Route',
   postmileField: 'DYNSEGPM',

   isVisible: false,
   template: {},
   panel: {},
   countyDllEl: {},
   routeDllEl: {},
   beginPostMarkerDdlEl: {},
   endPostMarkerDdlEl: {},

init: function () {
}, // init

show: function () {
   require(["dojo/on",
      "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dom-construct",
      "esri/tasks/QueryTask", "esri/tasks/query"
   ], function (on, declare, domConstruct, QueryTask, Query) {
         let ctx = app.utilitySelectorModule;
         ctx.isVisible = true;
         if (!ctx.panel.click) {
         ctx.panel = domConstruct.toDom("<div class='utilitySelectorPnl'>
</div>");
         domConstruct.place(ctx.panel, 'mainHtmlBody')
         template = $("#utilitySelectorTmpl");
         ctx.panel.innerHTML = template.html()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Brandon

Comment: Hi! Do you use dojo on top of some another app which isn't built with dojo? It would be cleaner, if you created templated widget and defined show/hide ot toggle function inside of it.

Comment: That's good advice. The app was made using dojo. I am trying to make customizations to it. Looks like jquery or javascript outside of the dojo framework may not be best.